# What does the term "pass" or "passing" something mean in JavaScript callbacks?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, timeout

Currently learning what callbacks mean in JavaScript and I'm struggling to grasp how callbacks work and the term passing this or passing that comes from and how it works with callbacks? I have some sample code that I would like to show and briefly explain why I don't get it.

```
var users = ["Sam", "Ellie", "Bryan"];

function addUser(username, chickenNugget) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      users.push(username);
      chickenNugget();
    }, 200);
}

function getUsers() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(users);
    }, 100);
}

addUser("Jake", getUsers);

getUsers();
```

What happens when chickenNugget is called? does the code in the function just stop when it hits chickenNugget and resets until the function addUser is called again?

Comment: *"why is the parameter chickenNugget classed as a callback"* - because... it's called back, by addUser?

Comment: New information added

Comment: There are no parameter types in JS, so `chickenNugget` is just a parameter you can pass anything to (`number`, `string`, `function`, `object`, ...) and also name it however you please.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Did you try running the code to see what it does? How does any of that relate to the title?

Comment: so i was watching a tutorial on callbacks and he was using different terms like this is passed to this and i'm like what does that mean, he used setTimeout to allow the callback to grab the data from addUser before getUsers even though getUsers was processed before when the callback wasn't implemented into the addUser codeblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callbacks are a way of handling asynchroncity in Javascript. Sometimes you have async functions which use stuff like `setTimeout` but you need to wait on those async functions to complete before you can continue running more of your code (which depends on the async request), and callbacks are a way of accomplishing that. I've updated your example to illustrate what I mean above, hopefully it's helpful:

```js
var users = ["Sam", "Ellie", "Bryan"];

function addUser(username, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      users.push(username);
      // this will be called only after username has been added to users
      callback();
    }, 200);
}

function isJakeInUsers() {
  if (users.includes("Jake")) {
    console.log("Jake is in users! :)");
  } else {
    console.log("Jake is not in users! :(");
  }
}

// as a callback, isJakeInUsers will only be called after "Jake" has been added to users
addUser("Jake", isJakeInUsers);

// this gets called immediately, before "Jake" has been added to users
isJakeInUsers();
```

Answer (score 1):

A callback is nothing more than instructions that are passed to be used at a later time. Callbacks are fundamental in javascript because it is an asynchronous language. Meaning that if an operation will require external services it will execute the next command without waiting for that operation to finish.

Here is an example of code executing synchronously

```
var total_in_cart = 0;
var shipping = 0;
var total = 0;

total_in_cart = 100; // USD
shipping = 10;
total = total_in_cart + shipping;
console.log(total);
```

this will output 110 as it waits for each line to finish executing before executing the next one.

Now here is an example of code executing asynchronously

```
var total_in_cart = 0;
var shipping = 0;
var total = 0;

total_in_cart = 100; // USD
shipping = get_shipping_fee_from_dhl_api();
total = total_in_cart + shipping;
console.log(total);
```

This will output 100 because JS is not waiting for the api call to finish and proceeds to execute the new line. To solve this you must send further instructions to be called back after the api request has completed hence the word callback.

So in this case you would have to wrap all your calculations into code that can be sent as a callback executable. In JS you would use a function and assign it to a variable which you will then pass on to the function that will take it and execute it.

Keep in mind that

```
function getUsers() {}
```

Is the same as

```
var getUsers = function() {};
```